# Pandas : transform a 2D dataframe to a 3D one

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I have a Pandas dataframe like :

```
     p1 p2 p3
t1   a  b  c
t2   d  e  f
t3   g  h  i
```

and I want either several df (or one xarray), one for each t(y axis)
like:

for t1: the value of pn minus pn for t1 :

```
     p1    p2   p3
p1   a-a  b-a  c-a 
p2   a-b  b-b  c-b
p3   a-c  b-c  c-c
```

idem for t2, t3 and so on...

I have made a loop like

```
for t in tlist :
    for p in plist :
        for q in plist :
            res = p - q
```

but it's hugly and slow.

So if anyone know a pythonic way to do that, [s]he's very welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a quite simple manner leveraging numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Let's try with the following ndarray:

```
a = np.random.randint(1,10,(3,3))

print(a)
array([[9, 6, 4],
       [2, 3, 6],
       [8, 9, 2]])

a[:,None] - a[...,None]

array([[[ 0, -3, -5],
        [ 3,  0, -2],
        [ 5,  2,  0]],

       [[ 0,  1,  4],
        [-1,  0,  3],
        [-4, -3,  0]],

       [[ 0,  1, -6],
        [-1,  0, -7],
        [ 6,  7,  0]]])
```

---

This works by adding new axes to the arrays in such a way, that subtracting them yields the desired cartesian operation, since:

```
print(a[:,None])

array([[[9, 6, 4]],

       [[2, 3, 6]],

       [[8, 9, 2]]])

print(a[...,None])

array([[[9],
        [6],
        [4]],

       [[2],
        [3],
        [6]],

       [[8],
        [9],
        [2]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with broadcasting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2],[3,6,8]])

# update as commented by piRSquared
a = df.to_numpy()    # use a=df.values if on Pandas < 0.24

a  = (a[:, None, :] - a[:,:,None]).reshape(-1, df.shape[1])

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df.index,df.columns), names=('t','p'))
pd.DataFrame(a, index=idx, columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
     0  1  2
t p         
0 0  0  1  2
  1 -1  0  1
  2 -2 -1  0
1 0  0  3  5
  1 -3  0  2
  2 -5 -2  0
```

Comment: Use `to_numpy` instead of `values`.  Assign result to an intermediate result to avoid running `to_numpy` twice. (`a = df.to_numpy(); a = (a[:, None, :] - a[:, :, None]).reshape(-1, df.shape[1])`.  Fantastic answer (-:

Comment: Thanks, updated. Although I'm not sure why the doc recommends `to_numpy()` over `.values`. For me it's longer and harder to type :-)

Comment: It is for me too.

Comment: @piRSquared @QuantHoangThe reasons for `to_numpy()` vs `.values` are [detailed here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics-attrs) . After a quick read, it does become clear about why to have `.to_numpy()` as a method (with the options of having arguments such as `dtype=`) rather than a plain property `.values`.

Comment: It works for me, didn't know about broadcasting... Thanks a lot !